# Soft Keyboard with FlipperView

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am using the `FlipperView` to create a wizard like process flow through my application. Within my Activity I inflate the various Views for each page of the flipper and add them in `onCreate()`.

My problem is that some of the **pages** contain `EditText` widgets and others contain none. If I leave the default *IMF* behaviour, the user is expected to touch into the `EditText` to show the keyboard. The problem then, is when they go to the next screen (without any `EditText`), the keyboard remains and must be manually hidden. Ideally it should be hidden again.

I have tried various calls to `showSoftInput()` or `toggleSoftInput()` but have not yet achieved the desired effect of automatically showing the keyboard when a page is shown with an `EditText`, and hiding when there is none.

**Is this possible?** I thought of calling `showSoftInput()` for each View added to my `FlipperView` where I want the keyboard shown, but this is not having the desired effect. Do I really have to call `showSoftInput()` for every `EditText` on my page (there could be 5-6)?

Have I missed something obvious here? If so sorry, I think I have got myself so confused with this `InputMethodManager.`